# FlutterContactPicker how to throw the error UserCancelledPickingException

Tags: flutter-layout

I am trying this code but give error!

```
try { contact = await FlutterContactPicker .pickPhoneContact(); } on PlatformException catch (e) { if (e.code == 'CANCELLED') { throw UserCancelledPickingException(); } rethrow; }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
on PlatformException
```

with

```
on UserCancelledPickingException {}
```